# Azure Service Bus trigger configuration for .NET Core 2.0 and Azure Web Jobs 3.0 is missing

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azureservicebus, azure-webjobssdk

I am working on a project where I want to implement Service Buss trigger in Web Job. I have followed the instructions here: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started.

```
 public class Functions
    {
        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(message);
        }
    }
```

But instead of storage queue (QueueTrigger) I want to use ServiceBus' Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBusTrigger. In the documentation states to use the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#service-bus-trigger-configuration-version-3x

```
static void Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddServiceBus(sbOptions =>
        {
            sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.AutoComplete = true;
            sbOptions.MessageHandlerOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls = 16;
        });
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that b.AddServiceBus is not even available (I have the latest Web Jobs version). So, when I run the project, I get "No job functions found" error. Any ideas or pointers?

I did try:

```
 public static void ProcessQueueMessage([Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBusTrigger("queue")] string message, ILogger logger)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(message);
        }
```

and

```
     public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("queue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "Endpoint=bla bla")]
string myQueueItem, Int32 deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, string messageId,ILogger log)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are packages you need.

1. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs(>= 3.0.10)
2. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions
3. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus
4. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus

`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus` this package is used to let you use `b.AddServiceBus()` method and the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` is used to create the `ServiceBusTrigger`.

The below is my code, you could have a test.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new HostBuilder();
        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddServiceBus();
        });
        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
        {
            b.AddConsole();
        });
        var host = builder.Build();
        using (host)
        {
            host.Run();
        }
    }
```

Functions.cs

```
public static void processservicebus(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("test", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]string myQueueItem,
    ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation(myQueueItem);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Worked perfectly!